# How do I get a new JSON entry in Elasticsearch for each file in the folder

Tags: node.js, angular, shell, express, elasticsearch

I have an asset folder with various mp3 files in a folder in Angular. I am accessing an empty Elasticsearch index through angular. For each file a document should be added to the Elasticsearch database. Each Item looks like this:

```
{
name: "Songname",
path: "../asset/mp3/",
genre: "pop, dance"
}
```

Of course, I could add each document manually with thousands of JSON entries of the mp3 files via "put" (name, path, genre), but that would take an enormous amount of time.  Therefore, I would like to write a script which reads the folder and creates a JSON object in Elasticsearch for each file.

After that I would only have to drop files into the folder and the index would fill automatically.

My question about this. Would I do the whole thing with a sh script or am I thinking too complicated here? Is there a simpler variant ? Alternatively about express JS? If it only works via the script, how would the structure of the script look like and could I also read metadata via the mp3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use elasticsearch's Bulk Insert API for speeding up your insert times.
You can read more about it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html
You can also see an example of how to it in Node here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/bulk_examples.html

If you plan on running this periodically, I would think about how to avoid Re-inserting files (You can either take files from a certain update date, or set a custom id so re-inserting them wouldn't cause duplicates)